# Testing web API using jasmine and node.js

Tags: node.js, jasmine

We've written a RESTful web API which responds to GET and PUT requests using node.js.
We're having some difficulties testing the API.
First, we used [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), but it's not well documented so we couldn't get it to make PUT requests:

```
var zombie = require("zombie");

describe("description", function() {
  it("description", function() {
    zombie.visit("http://localhost:3000/", function (err, browser, status) {
      expect(browser.text).toEqual("A")
    });
  });
});
```

After that we tried using a REST-client called [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler), which would OK, since we don't need any advanced browser simulation. This fails due to the fact that the request seems to be asynchronous - i.e. the test is useless since it finishes before the 'on success' callback is called:

```
var rest = require('restler');
describe("description", function() {
  it("description", function() {
    rest.get("http://www.google.com").on('complete', function(data, response) {
      // Should fail
      expect(data).toMatch(/apa/i);
    });
  });
});
```

We'd grateful for any tips about alternative testing frameworks or synchronous request clients.

Comment: it won't give you RESTful testing, but [vows](http://vowsjs.org/) is a pretty good node.js based testing framework.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious about this so I did a little more research. Other than [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), you have a couple of options...

You could use [vows](http://vowsjs.org/) with the http library [like this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311946/async-testing-with-vows-using-the-http-get-library-in-node-js).

However, I think a better approach might be to use APIeasy, which is apparently built on [vows](http://vowsjs.org/). There is an [awesome article over at nodejitsu that explains how to use it](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/rest-easy-test-any-api-in-nodejs).

Another interesting idea is to use [expresso](http://visionmedia.github.com/expresso/) if you are using express.

Answer (score 4):

For node, jasmine-node from Misko Hevery has asynchronous support and wraps jasmine.

https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

You add a 'done' parameter to the test signature, and call that when the asynchronous call completes. You can also customize the timeout (the default is 500ms).

e.g. from the Github README

```
it("should respond with hello world", function(done) {
  request("http://localhost:3000/hello", function(error, response, body){
    done();
  }, 250);  // timeout after 250 ms
});
```

jasmine regular also has support for asynchronous testing with runs and waitsFor, or can use 'done' with Jasmine.Async.